# Asbestos ceiling tiles or not?

Tags: ceiling, asbestos

Recently I saw a documentary about asbestos and it freaked me out a little.
The reason is that in 2012 some friends and I visited an old and abandoned amusement park to do an airsoft battle.  At the time, I didn't really worry about asbestos. But after watching the documentary I rewatched my GoPro footage of that day and wondered if I came into contact with asbestos.

Following is a screenshot of some ceiling tiles that were laying over there. There are markings on the back but they are incomplete.  Could those contain asbestos?

[image]

Comment: VTC as off-topic, since it's not about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Nope: That's modern drywall (a.k.a. gypsum board, a.k.a. Sheetrock).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the ceiling tiles are sheetrock, but my answer is effectively the same that it's probably not dangerous.

It appears to be *tegular*  (having a rabbet cut around the edge) ceiling tiles manufactured by Armstrong in a year where laser imprinting of the backs of the tiles was possible.  03/03 date on one of them might be day and month or month and year, but in any case they are highly unlikely to contain asbestos.

From their FAQ:
2 - What do your mineral fibre tiles consist of?
Our mineral fibre tiles are made from a combination of the following naturally occuring, processed and recycled materials in varying proportions depending upon the tile type: mineral wool, clay, perlite, cellulose and starch mixed together in a water based process before being cured by heat. They are then finished with a water based paint, or laminated scrim and paint, decorative facing. All these materials are environmentally safe and our factories comply with ISO 14001.
**Note: Asbestos, in any form, is not and never has been used in the manufacture of Armstrong ceiling tiles**.

http://www.armstrong.co.hu/commclgeu/eu1/uk/hu/FAQ_other.html

https://www.armstrongceilings.com/commercial/en-us/commercial-ceilings-walls/ultima-lay-in-and-tegular-ceiling-tiles.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm glad I don't have to worry about this.